# Ruby gsub same format for all 3 but 1 of them outputs differently

Tags: ruby, gsub

Im trying to add html tags around certain text criteria via regex .
Right now, I have * and ** working (adding h1 and h2 tags)

I have the same format for the li tag, but it adds the closing tag next to the opening, which is not what I want.

Why is the output different?

:::TEXT FILE::::

```
* this is an awesome *
** this could be something better **
* another test *
- li are good for lists
```

::: END TEXT FILE :::

:::MY OUTPUT:::

```
-bash-4.1$ ruby markup.rb testMarkup.txt
<h1>this is an awesome <\h1>
<h2> this could be something better <\h2>
<h1>another test <\h1>
<li><\li>li are good for lists
```

:: END OUTPUT:::

:: Ruby File ::

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

text = IO.read(ARGV[0])

text = text.gsub(/^\*{1}[^*](.*?)\*{1}\s/) do 
  "<h1>" + $1 + "<\\h1>" 
end

text = text.gsub(/^\*{2}(.*?)(\*{2})\s/) do 
  "<h2>" + $1 + "<\\h2>" 
end

text = text.gsub(/^[-](.*?)\s/) do 
   "<li>" + $1 + "<\\li>" 
end
puts text
```

:: END RUBY FILE ::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last regexp, `/^[-](.*?)\s/` you should add `$` in the end of the regexp to match only the whole line starting with **-**.

`/^[-](.*?)\s/` matches string " -" and replaces it, leaving the rest of the string unmodified.

FYI, you can simplify your solution, turning it into a more generic one. Declare a hash with pairs of type `Regexp => tag`, then iterate over it. You will like the code! Feel free to ask for further help.

P.S. I guess, you are trying to convert Markdown into HTML. Allthough it's a very good excercise to write it yourself, you can use a ready solution, like [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The crucial difference is that, in the regex for the tags `h1` and `h2`:

```
/^\*{1}[^*](.*?)\*{1}\s/
/^\*{2}(.*?)(\*{2})\s/
```

the string to be captured, matching `(.*?)`, has to be followed by a special terminating symbol `\*{1}` or `\*{2}`, which lets the non-greedy match to wait for such special characters, whereas in the regex for the tag `li`:

```
/^[-](.*?)\s/
```

the string to be captured only needs to be followed by a more general character `\s`, which is already met right after `-`, so the non-greedy match does not extend beyond that.